# During a subprocess call, catch critical windows errors in Python instead of letting the OS handle it by showing nasty error pop-ups

Tags: python, windows, subprocess

"The application failed to initialize properly ... Click on OK,to terminate the application." is the message from the error pop-up. What is the way to catch these errors in Python code?

Comment: -1: not a question. Please use question/answer format on this site (even if you write both)

Comment: Yes, you pose the question as How do you catch.... then click the answer button and put your code/workaround in the answer. Then people can rate your solution independently of your question.

Comment: Answer is now in the answers section; also this question is now a 'community wiki'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds familiar? This will block your `subprocess.Popen` forever.. until you click the 'OK' button. Add the following code to your module initialization to workaround this issue:

```
import win32api, win32con
win32api.SetErrorMode(win32con.SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS |
                      win32con.SEM_NOOPENFILEERRORBOX)
```